# What causes an h3 to ignore the div and require large margins to be moved below it?

Tags: html, css

I have been styling the following html snippet:

```css
/*With this code for devices with min-width of 769px:*/

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .event-details h3 {
    margin-top: 5.5em;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  /* Event status section */
  .event-status-box {
    h3 {
      padding-bottom: 0;
      padding-top: 0 !important;
    }
    padding:1em;
    div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .event-edit-btns {
      width: 50%;
      float: right;
      text-align: right;
      margin-top: -0.15em;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="event-details">
  <h1>Edit Event</h1>

  <div class="col xs-12 event-status-box">

    <h3>Event Status</h3>

    <div class="event-status-agenda">
      Approved:<i ng-class="eventDetails.status == 'approved' ? 'fa fa-check' : 'fa fa-close'"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="event-status-agenda">
      Under Review:<i ng-class="eventDetails.status == NULL ? 'fa fa-check' : 'fa fa-close'"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="event-status-agenda">
      Rejected:<i ng-class="eventDetails.status == 'rejected' ? 'fa fa-check' : 'fa fa-close'"></i>
    </div>


    <div class="event-edit-btns">

      <!--Update-->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-update-event">Update</button>

      <!-- Add Attendee -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-add-attendee" ng-click="">Add Attendee</button>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- closes .event-status-box -->

  <h3>Event Details</h3>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form"></form>

</div>
<!-- closes .event-details -->
```

Why would .event-details h3 require exorbitant amounts of margin to be a bit more below the div?

Here's a screenshot (if I remove that margin and add a background color):[image: screenshot of the problem]

I just want to know what's causing this behavior or how I can semantically write it so it actually listens to the classes and things without assigning properties to ALL h3s on the page. >.<

Comment: Can you replicate it in a JSFiddle or provide us a link to the page?

Comment: I've placed your code into a snippet. I'm not prepared to alter your markup, but there's a typo with `.event-status-box {` within your CSS. Please edit to what this *should* be. (I don't want to alter your actual code)

Comment: I must be staring at it for too long because I am not seeing a typo anywhere in that css... Not to argue with you, I just don't see it.

Comment: @VarvaraJones I cant replicate the gap in your screen shot with the code you provided, there must be some other css at work - can you give us a link to the page?

Comment: Per the nature of the project (something I'm doing at work) I can't post this online. Just thought someone might have an idea. I found a workaround (adding that extra margin) and I'll keep combing through it. Sorry if I wasn't very helpful in letting you awesome people replicated the problem.

Comment: Looks like SCSS to me but I'm not sure exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Right. The snippets here don't do SCSS, so the result of the snippet in the question is not what the OP intended.

Comment: @VarvaraJones have your tried inspecting it using chrome dev tools? They are great for seeing what is adding or removing css etc

Comment: @CalvT, yes, I'm combing through it right now, and always do. Love Chrome tools. ;)

Comment: @Paulie_D, the issue is that the whole red background in that screenshot applies to EVENT DETAILS header, which means it's not calculating the margin from the bottom of the div previous to that but instead from the top of mother div. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Not really. It's hard to diagnose an image.